# MongoDB update timeseries rename field

Tags: mongodb

In a timeseries collection I have 4 documents which have a field with a wrong name ("itemUrl" should be "item").

The documents with mistakes look like this one:

```
{
  "timestamp": {
    "$date": "2023-10-08T19:07:32.694Z"
  },
  "minPrice": 5,
  "maxOffer": 7,
  "itemUrl": "foo",
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6522e1d4c168e0b29ef203ff"
  }
}
```

So I opened MongoDB Compass and in the shell I am trying to execute the following:

```
db.prices.updateMany(
  { itemUrl: {$exists: true}},
  { $rename: { "itemUrl": "item" } }
)
```

And I get the error:

```
MongoServerError: Cannot perform an update on a time-series collection that does not have a metaField
```

I clearly don't understand timeseries collections well enough to understand the error message, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to a plain vanilla collection, there are some limitations when updating data in a time series collection. See the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/#updates) for a list of limitations dependent on the version of MongoDB you are using.

As regards the error described in the question, one of the limitations is that you can only filter for a `meta` field when updating. However, the error states that there is no meta field defined on the collection.

I suspect that `itemUrl` or ìtem` is not a value that you want to monitor, but an identifier that describes where the value comes from. This is a good candidate for a meta field.

Unfortunately, it is a bit complicated to fix errors like this with the limitations that are imposed by a time series collection up to now.

Your best bet is to use an aggregation to fix the errors in the schema and move the documents into a new - standard - collection.

Afterwards, you can use `mongodump` to export the data in the new collection. Then you create a new time series collection that sets the correct meta field(s) and use `mongorestore` to import the documents into the new collection, e.g.

```
db.prices.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "item": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$item",
          "$itemUrl"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "itemUrl"
  },
  {
    $merge: "new_collection"
  }
]);
```

Of course, you can also drop the existing time series collection and create it with the correct meta field under the same name, but you should test the approach before. Also, please check whether the approach works for the amount of data in your environment.

The [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/) describes the characteristics and limitations of time series collections and also covers the relevant use cases.

Comment: So basically the mistake was in the collection definition and there is no way to fix except recreating the collection?

Comment: Yes, up to now you cannot change the meta (and timestamp) field: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/#modification-of-timefield-and-metafield